# Do we have any File Table / File Stream like support in any other database than MS SQL Server?

Tags: database-recommendation, filestream

I am looking for an alternative to Microsoft SQL Server's File Tables / File Stream feature. The reason is because I really wanted to use SQL Server File Tables but I am on Linux and using docker.

Unfortunately, Microsoft does not provide any support for Linux when it comes to File Tables. See [this Issue](https://github.com/microsoft/mssql-docker/issues/47) which is still open. MySQL or PostgreSQL is preferable though.

SQL Server File Tables uses Operating System's File System to store files and synchronize these file values in SQL Tables. It is much faster than saving a BLOB. Also, it is backed up if I run Database Backup. So, its using File System for speed but also keeping it synchronized with Database. I can also access the files via File System and / or via transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The alternative implementation in the past was to store the files on a shared location and store their location's reference in the database in a table.

Here are the current options for modern DBMS:

- Oracle PL/SQL - [Loading documents and other file data into the Oracle Database](https://blogs.oracle.com/searchtech/loading-documents-and-other-file-data-into-the-oracle-database): Full Text or Binary Data with BFiles or External Tables might be closest to what your use case is.
- MySQL: [BLOB Storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5959043/how-to-insert-a-file-in-mysql-database): Seems like there's not much alternative in MySQL (aside from storing the reference to the file's location).
- PostgreSQL: [Storing Binary Data](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.4/jdbc-binary-data.html) & [Are there performance issues storing files in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9605922/are-there-performance-issues-storing-files-in-postgresql): Can use the bytea data type or the Large Object feature which stores the data in dedicated table.
- MongoDB: [BSON Types](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/index.html) & [GridFS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/): BSON data types can store data up to 16 MB in size, after that GridFS is the solution for larger storage (especially for binary data).
- SQLite: [Can we store .doc .pdf and .jpg files in SQLite Database (Android)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29008721/can-we-store-doc-pdf-and-jpg-files-in-sqlite-database-android)
   & [Datatypes in SQLite Version 3](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html): BLOBs are the go-to in SQLite.
- MariaDB: [LOAD_FILE](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/load_file/): There doesn't seem to be a lot of support in MariaDB at all, but in general they also use BLOB storage have a LOAD_FILE function.
- AWS: [SimpleDB](https://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/): While this isn't achievable via Docker, just for reference for anyone adamant about storing files in the database, their SimpleDB (among some of their other services) offer ways to somewhat store files in the database and use meta-data to tag what kind of file they are (typically leveraging S3 buckets).

[Here's also an oldie but goodie on the pros and cons of storing large files in the database.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/150669/is-it-a-bad-practice-to-store-large-files-10-mb-in-a-database)

Comment: That is not an alternative to File Tables actually. It is way before File Stream and File Table Support. When someone store files on a shared location, it is not backed up with database backups (you do it manually). Database don't synchronize files with records in tables. So if some files are deleted mistakenly from file system, they will still be there in database records. You will only get error when you attempt to read a file which is shown in database but does not exist in reality.

Comment: @Imran Faruqi actually it's been the popular choice of storing files coupled to the database even when FileTables were available. Here's some related Brent Ozar posts that mention them: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2015/03/no-more-blobs/ and https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/brent/what-im-telling-my-clients-about-sql-server-denali/ He actually even briefly touches on the issues you can encounter using FileTables with no transaction log on top of them (so there's no perfect solution either way). That being said, I think the answer I provided is unfortunately the closest you're going to get.

Comment: I understand the pros and cons and I really appreciate your help in this. I actually don't know the name of the feature other companies call it. Like there must be something in Oracle SQL, PostgreSQL or MySQL similar to MS SQL Server File Tables or File Stream support. Microsoft can barely be the one bringing one sort of feature alone.

Comment: @ImranFaruqi Unfortunately MS SQL Server is where I'm most versed with, so I can't say for sure completely with the other more Linux favorable RDBMS if they don't have an equivalent. I'll have to do some research and will keep you updated if I find any equivalent, though I do know some of the features MS SQL Server offers are pretty unique to Microsoft.

Comment: @ImranFaruqi Unfortunately not much success in finding a true comparable alternative to Microsoft's solution, but I did update my answer with the general options among the other modern database management systems, hopefully you find some use out of this information. If I find anything else, I'll continue to update my answer.

Comment: @Imran Faruqi No problem! Sorry I couldn't turn up a better solution. The final thoughts I'll add is it's probably easier for Microsoft to implement this kind of feature in SQL Server since they created the Windows File System, as opposed to the other database system's who did not invent the Linux File System.

Comment: Really appreciate your efforts! :)